# Applying PURE html in view (.ctp file) in CakePHP

Tags: html, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I just want to ask if it is possible to create a ctp file with pure html? Like for example, I want to add a form and my code will be:

```
<form>First name:<br><input type="text" name="firstname"><br>Last name:<br><input type="text" name="lastname"></form>
```

and not like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php __('Add User'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('lastname');
    echo $this->Form->input('firstname');
    echo $this->Form->input('email');
    echo $this->Form->input('organizer_pic');
    echo $this->Form->input('description');
    echo $this->Form->input('website');
    echo $this->Form->input('company');
    echo $this->Form->input('organization');
    echo $this->Form->input('contact_num');
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Form->input('group_id');
?>
</fieldset><?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
```

Do you guys think it is possible? I want it to be pure html because I'm having a hard time in creating a good layout with Bootstrap. I'm using CakePHP 1.3. Please let me know if you have an idea.

Comment: Of course it's possible, just like it's possible to have a `.php` file that only contains HTML.

Comment: so can I use PURE html? Like this 
<form action="localhost/controller/function" method='post'> 
  <input name="data[Model][tablename]" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
</form> @scrowler

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<form action="/project_name/users/add" id="UserAddForm" method="post">
   First name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="data[User][firstname]"><br>
   Last name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="data[User][lastname]"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I think this not recomended solution

Use these keys if you need to inject some markup inside the output of the input() method:

```
echo $this->Form->input('field', array(
    'before' => '--before--',
    'after' => '--after--',
    'between' => '--between---'
));
```

Output:

```
<div class="input">
--before--
<label for="UserField">Field</label>
--between---
<input name="data[User][field]" type="text" value="" id="UserField" />
--after--
</div>
```

Lot more customization can be done refer to following link

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options

Comment: That's what I asked. :) Thanks @Abhijeet :)

Comment: I didn't press the button down. @Abhijeet.

Comment: Writing forms in CakePHP like this and not using the Form helper is not recommended. If you write form in plain html you will loose all the magic of the CakePHP form helper. You will need to do everything manually. Form values populating, validation errors display etc. Boostrap compatible form output is possible with CakePHP 1.3 Form helper without big problems. You just need to play with Form defaults per each form or create your own FormHelper wich will produce bootstrap compatible forms by default. All you need is to study the Form helper docs and  try  it :)

Comment: Do you think so @thanat? Because I'm having a hard time especially on Javasscript. It's like it didn't work well. And I don't know why. I'm using CakePHP 1.3 with Bootstrap 3.0 integrated. And I used a lot of javascript. I don't know if I'm using Javascript well. I'm newbie in CakePHP. And I'm studying only all by myself. So, I don't know if I'm doing it right. I'm used to create PHP apps in a native/root way.

Comment: ya that is not a recomended solution @nosnevetzy tell me exactly what problem you have

Comment: On another note, if you're a newbie with Cake, use a more recent version!

Answer (score 1):

You can have pure html on a ctp file but you need to have an action in your controller as well. You can leave the action empty.

Comment: If i leave the action empty, how about if I'm gonna make two forms in one ctp file?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just so that we are in the page, are you submitting the form to the same action?

Comment: I used to write pure html and didn't prefer the cakephp convention. Ignore my "you can leave the action empty" comment and my followup comment too. Do as you please with the actions. But a straight answer to your question. You can have pure html in ctp. :P

Answer (score -1):

```
You should try this
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                <?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend><?php __('Add User'); ?></legend>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>Username</label>
                                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('lastname',array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>false,'div'=>false));
                                    ?>
                                    <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>firstname</label>
                                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('firstname',array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>false,'div'=>false));
                                    ?>
                                    <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>Email</label>
                                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('email',array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>false,'div'=>false));
                                    ?>
                                    <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>organizer_pic</label>
                                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('organizer_pic',array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>false,'div'=>false));
                                    ?>
                                    <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>description</label>
                                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('description',array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>false,'div'=>false));
                                    ?>
                                    <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>website</label>
                                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('website',array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>false,'div'=>false));
                                    ?>
                                    <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>company</label>
                                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('company',array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>false,'div'=>false));
                                    ?>
                                    <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>organization</label>
                                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('organization',array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>false,'div'=>false));
                                    ?>
                                    <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>contact number</label>
                                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('contact_num',array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>false,'div'=>false));
                                    ?>
                                    <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>username</label>
                                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('username',array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>false,'div'=>false));
                                    ?>
                                    <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>password</label>
                                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('password',array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>false,'div'=>false));
                                    ?>
                                    <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                    <label>group id</label>
                                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('group_id',array('class'=>'form-control','label'=>false,'div'=>false));
                                    ?>
                                    <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                     <?php
                     echo $this->Form->button('Submit',array('class'=>'btn btn-success btn-xs','div'=>false),array('escape'=>false)
                            );
                     ?>
                     </div>
                </fieldset><?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
                </div>
                </div>
```

### Output

[image]

### Html output

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                               <form action="/BTSSO/Users/demo/" id="UserDemoForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div>            <fieldset>
                      <legend></legend>
                      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                      <label>Username</label>
                                      <input name="data[User][lastname]" class="form-control" type="text" id="UserLastname"/>                                <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                      <label>firstname</label>
                                      <input name="data[User][firstname]" class="form-control" type="text" id="UserFirstname"/>                                <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                      <label>Email</label>
                                      <input name="data[User][email]" class="form-control" type="email" id="UserEmail"/>                                <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                      </div>
                       <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                      <label>organizer_pic</label>
                                      <input name="data[User][organizer_pic]" class="form-control" type="text" id="UserOrganizerPic"/>                                <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                      <label>description</label>
                                      <input name="data[User][description]" class="form-control" type="text" id="UserDescription"/>                                <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                      </div>
                       <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                      <label>website</label>
                                      <input name="data[User][website]" class="form-control" type="text" id="UserWebsite"/>                                <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                      </div>
                       <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                      <label>company</label>
                                      <input name="data[User][company]" class="form-control" type="text" id="UserCompany"/>                                <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                      </div>
                       <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                      <label>organization</label>
                                      <input name="data[User][organization]" class="form-control" type="text" id="UserOrganization"/>                                <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                      <label>contact number</label>
                                      <input name="data[User][contact_num]" class="form-control" type="text" id="UserContactNum"/>                                <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                      <label>username</label>
                                      <input name="data[User][username]" class="form-control" maxlength="255" type="text" id="UserUsername" required="required"/>                                <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                      </div>
                       <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                      <label>password</label>
                                      <input name="data[User][password]" class="form-control" type="password" id="UserPassword" required="required"/>                                <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                      </div>
                       <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                      <label>group id</label>
                                      <select name="data[User][group_id]" class="form-control" id="UserGroupId">
                          </select>  <i class="icon-users form-control-feedback"></i>
                      </div>
                         <div class="form-group has-feedback">

                   <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs"  type="submit">Submit</button>                        </div>
                  </fieldset>
            </form>            
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @vikram for this. I tried the code you've just posted above. But I sitill having a problem especially when I'm started to add Javascript inside my code. But thanks for sharing! :)